# Is there a way to mimic the behavior of <select> element when its parent's overflow property is set to hidden?

Tags: html, css

I was just designing my own website (even though it's technically not) when I stumbled a very interesting behavior of the `<select>` element.
Due to the need of styling and putting things instead of plain texts inside `<option>` element, I decided to custom-made my own `<select>` element using `<div>` and `<ul>`, where those elements are contained inside a parent with a style of `overflow:hidden`.

I have tried to understand the quirks of `float` and `overflow` property and also the `appearance` property but I don't think that any of them can help me solve this problem.

Here is [the link](https://codepen.io/undefined_overflow/pen/PoYQNpr) to this problem.

It was as I expected that my custom `<select>` element did not show properly; however, the original `<select>` element did show the `<option>` parts regardless its parent's `overflow` property was set to `hidden` or not.
Therefore, I want to know if there is anyway to hack around this problem? I know that I can just use `<select>` element so I wouldn't feel any pain figuring this out. But I just purely curious about any work-around of this. Many thanks.

**EDIT**: Here's the code :

**HTML**:

```
<div class="top">
  <!-- Custom <select> element -->
  <div class="test_1">
    <!-- Position custom element -->
    <div class="test_padding vertical_middle">
      <!-- Makes both the chooser and the list to have position:relative -->
      <div class="test_rel">
        <!-- Chooser for user to click on -->
        <div class="test_chooser">
          <span>List1</span>
        </div>
        <!--
            Dropdown list that is cropped by overflow:hidden when this list is 
            shown after clicking
        -->
        <ul class="test_list no_margin no_padding">
          <li>List1</li>
          <li>List2</li>
          <li>List3</li>
          <li>List4</li>
          <li>List5</li>
          <li>List6</li>
          <li>List7</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Original <select> element -->
  <div class="test_2">
    <!--
        <option> elements are not cropped on clicking <select> 
        element eventhough it belongs to that element, which is 
        contained inside an element that has overflow:hidden set

        It just as if <option> elements have a fixed position and
        z-index of a very large number, which are not shown through
        developer's tool
    -->
    <select class="vertical_middle">
      <option>Option1</option>
      <option>Option2</option>
      <option>Option3</option>
      <option>Option4</option>
      <option>Option5</option>
      <option>Option6</option>
      <option>Option7</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{background:#222;}
.no_margin{ margin:0; }
.no_padding{ padding:0; }
.vertical_middle{ top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); }

/*
  The outtermost top navigation that has its property has overflow is set to 
  hidden
*/
.top{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background:#000;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  color:#eee;
  overflow:hidden;
}

/*
  First test
  This is a custom made <select> element
*/
.test_1{ float:left; }
/* Padding in order to position the element */
.test_padding{
  height:1.65em;
  position: absolute;
  border:1px solid rgb(169,169,169);
  width:10%;
  left:5%;
}
/*
   Makes every of its child has the position of relative for less pain in 
   seperating the main box and the below list
*/
.test_rel{
  position:relative;
  font-size:1.15em;
}
.test_rel *{ position:inherit; }
/*
  Main box that contains the name of the first value and for user to drop
  down the list below on a click
*/
.test_chooser{
  padding:3px 0 0 3px;
  top:0;
}
/*
   List below for choosing, which should be the same as <option> element.
   Unfortunately, this list is cropped out due to overflow:hidden of its
   parent
*/
.test_list{
  padding:0;
  margin:1px 0 0 2px;
  list-style:none;
 }
.test_list > li{
  padding:3px 0;
  z-index:1000;
}

/*
  Second test which contains the original <select> element
*/
.test_2{ float:right; }
/*
  This <select> element has an unknown quirk that allows its list <option>
  elements to be shown regardless of overflow:hidden that is set by its
  parent when user clicks on it!
*/
.test_2 select{
  position:absolute;
  right:5%;
  width:10vw;
  font-size:1.1em;
  padding:3px;
}
```

**EDIT #2** So to simplify my question furthermore, is there a way to make the list below my custom  element to be shown regardless of any odds (`overflow:hidden` for example), just like the original  element?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put it in the question itself instead.

Comment: @wazz Well, I use XAMPP as a web server and I also do not have domain name so how can I post that link? I also put my effort in creating a pen on codepen.io that represent my problem so I don't know if my link simply does not work or did I miss something? May be I should clarify more about my question.

Comment: You don't even have a properly functioning custom dropdown in your example. Why are you worried about the overflow at this point.

Comment: If I put the code so that the element is functioned properly, in the end, the problem would just turn into the overflow problem.